# «Enligner», un terme compréhensible?

Tags: vocabulaire, québec, régionalismes

Au Québec, les termes *aligner* et *enligner* (et leurs dérivés) sont pour beaucoup interchangeables. Ce n'est pas que tous les utilisent l'un pour l'autre, mais presque tous comprendront le sens d'une phrase contenant l'un ou l'autre.

Le second terme, cependant, n'est pas répertorié par la plupart des dictionnaires usuels, et son usage est restreint au domaine architectural lorsqu'il est présent.

À cause de sa grande présence au Québec, l'Office québécois de la langue française (OQLF) se devait d'en discuter. Il en indique la restriction déjà mentionné et déconseille son usage en tout autre circonstance, dont lorsqu’il est utilisé à la place d’*aligner*.

L’usage de ces deux termes (puisqu’ils sont plus ou moins interchangeables, les erreurs étant suffisament fréquentes pour habituer nos oreilles à celles-ci) lorsqu’il est question du parallélisme des roues d’un véhicule est infligé de la marque infamante par excellence de l’OQLF, l’[emprunt à l’anglais](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3975), et de ce fait déconseillé dans la «langue soignée».

Je m'arrête à cet usage critiqué. L'OQLF me semble, des deux, préférer le terme *alignement*, puisque qu’*enlignement* est alors un mauvais choix de mot en plus de l’emprunt à l’anglais qu’était déjà l’acception du bon mot (propriété transitive non-transformationnelle).

Je comprends pourtant *alignement* comme une suite, une séquence, la réduction à une seule ligne, et non pas à n'importe laquelle de ses parallèles, alors qu'*enlignement* pourrait inclure toute ligne parallèle à une première donnée. La gradation de l'OQLF me semble donc inversée par rapport à mon usage: je privilégie *enlignement* à *alignement*. Quant à l'expression proposée en remplacement, sa longueur et sa rareté dans l'usage local véritable me la font bouder sans vergogne.

- Est-ce que je me trompe sur *alignement*?
- Des Québécois pourraient-ils comparer leur compréhension personnelle d'*enlignement* à la mienne?

Pour *enligner*, il existe par ailleurs d'autres nuances de sens bien vivantes au Québec:

> **Enligner quelqu'un**:
>   • 1) Le regarder droit dans les yeux avec insistence, souvent avec désapprobation, mais peut aussi s'appliquer à une tentative de reconnaissance d'une personne (suite à une longue séparation ou à cause d'une mauvaise vision: myopie, obscurité, distance, ...). Comme les humains ont généralement deux yeux, on fait suivre à son regard deux droites sub-parallèles, d'où l'idée qu'alignement ne conviendrait pas aussi bien.
>   • 2) Lui indiquer les grandes lignes d'un projet et le détail des étapes à suivre, afin que la personne soit à peu près autonome pour la tâche assignée. *Enligner ses enfant dans la vie:* leur donner les outils qui les rendront aptes à tirer leur épingle du jeu dans la société.
>   **S'enligner vers quelque part** ou **s'enligner par là-bas**:
>   • Entreprendre un déplacement vers le point indiqué (en suivant approximativement la ligne joignant son point actuel et la destination).
>   • *Au figuré* Tendre ses efforts vers la réalisation d’un projet (*s’enligner vers la mise en marché d’un produit*) ou indiquer que les séquence espérée des évènements suit son cours et que les résultats espérés surviendront (*s’enligner vers un accord*).

- Dans quelle mesure ces utilisations seraient-elles comprises ailleurs dans la Francophonie?

Comment: The way I read the OQLF page, it doesn't say that *enligner* is borrowed from English, but that the nominal derivation "alignement" is. Neither *enligner* nor *enlignement* are likely to come from English, which has no such term! (In fact, *enlignement* would be a naturalized version of the ambiguously English *alignement* to match the unambiguously French *enligner*.) It's thus recommending *parallélisme* over either of the *-ment* ones without discrimination.

Comment: (If I read your question right, that's not a core point anyway, which seems to be whether *enlignement* is indeed more familiar than *alignement* as they claim, but I'm referring to the last sentence of your second paragraph.)

Comment: I may have been a little unclear and I also tend to be a little sarcastic towards OQLF & its recommendations. They do mention that _alignement_ for _parallélisme des roues_ is «borrowed» from English. But then, they tend to give this word a better status than _enlignement_, for the latter one is to be used only as a specific technical term, or otherwise is a mispronounciation of _alignement_, which makes it doubly bad.

Comment: En Français de France, _enligner_ est assez inconnu dans la vie courante.

Comment: Luke, you're right, I was wrong. I'll get things straightened up. Thanks.

Comment: Looks good. Now if only I was in a position to answer the question...

Comment: Remarque, ma compréhension de ce mot est peut-être strictement personnelle. J'espère que des Canadiens-Français aideront à clarifier cette zone grise (que certaines autorités linguistiques préféreraient peut-être balayée sous le tapis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Je comprends différemment l'article à la BDL quant à l'idée qu'on préférerait l'*alignement* à l'*enlignement* pour le parallélisme des roues. Comme vous le mentionnez, je comprends qu'autant *alignement* qu'*enlignement* seraient à proscrire dans l'article et cette interprétation s'arrime avec le contenu d'une vieille entrée au GDT ([parallélisme des roues](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=18947974), 1991, pour *wheel alignment* ; je veux dire qu'il n'est pas fait mention d'*alignement* en français.). Je saisis qu'*enlignement* est de surcroît normalement réservé aux emplois techniques et donc qu'il serait à proscrire doublement, si l'on veut. Quelles roues sont enlignées/alignées sur lesquelles : je dirais que par exemple en avant, la gauche et la droite sont communément *alignées* (sur le même axe, celui de l'*essieu*, et si l'essieu est droit elle sont alors parallèles, mais pas enlignées sur la même ligne), alors que les deux gauches (avant et arrière) sont *enlignées* (sur la même ligne, celle sur/dans laquelle avancent les roues/le véhicule) mais lors d'un échange avec quelqu'un nous n'étions pas du même avis quant à l'axe de référence, me rappelant un débat, il y a fort longtemps, sur le sens de la *largeur/longueur*, un genre d'hésitation géométrique. Mais je pense que l'analyse qui précède ne tient pas compte de la réalité de l'entretien des véhicules ni de leurs [caractéristiques](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%A9om%C3%A9trie_de_suspension), dont j'ignore tout en fait, et qui font que la roue n'est pas que boulonnée au bout de l'essieu et que l'entretien vise plusieurs couples de roues différents ; le parallélisme met l'accent sur les angles et la direction plus simplement à mon avis, évacuant la question de la ligne identique ou non. Mais assurément mon usage personnel diffère de ce qu'on dit d'*enligner* à la BDL ou au [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/enligner) puisque l'un et l'autre ne semblent pas interchangeables chez moi...

Plus généralement, je ne savais même pas qu'*enligner* n'était pas courant ou surtout réservé à des emplois techniques et je l'utilise à souhait au Québec. Quand je pense à la piste d'athlétisme ou à la piscine, à ces couloirs, à la ligne de départ etc. j'utilise *enligner* et *aligner* puisque les coureurs peuvent être dans l'un ou l'autre de ces états mais différemment, comme vous le dites en [commentaire](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/25295/enligner-un-terme-compr%C3%A9hensible#comment49980_25295). *Les coureurs se sont alignés sur la ligne de départ avec enthousiasme*, nous dit la BDL en exemple, soit *rangés sur la même ligne*, celle du départ, unique. Par ailleurs je dirais sans hésiter qu'ils sont *enlignés dans leur couloir respectif*, dans l'axe de ce couloir; une seule ligne par coureur, de multiples coureurs, de multiples lignes parallèles. Peut-être que la morphologie de ces verbes rappellent une préposition qu'on associe à *à la ligne/en ligne*. Peut-être que c'est pour ça que j'avais dit *enligner bout à bout les feuilles* ailleurs, je pensais à les relier sur leur longueur, et non de les aligner de côté ; quoique pour les pages d'un livre, mon hésitation soit totale, et j'aurais peut-être dit génériquement *égales*. Au TLFi on nous dit qu'avec *être/se mettre en ligne* on peut avoir la notion d'alignement dans le sens d'une « série de personnes alignées les unes à côté des autres ou les unes derrière les autres [...] » ; dans mon usage c'est semble-t-il *enligner* qui signale cette nuance *d'aligné l'un derrière l'autre*...

---

Ma compréhension de l'usage de ces deux verbes est, si j'ai bien compris, assez proche de la vôtre.

Comment: @Feelew J'ai repris mes commentaires et j'ai tenté de présenter ce que j'en pense. Merci !

Comment: Merci beaucoup de votre réponse. Nous avons en effet tous deux l'idée d'une nuance entre les deux verbes, bien qu'un peu difficile à cerner. Peut-être que le désir des références linguistiques québécoises de ne pas reconnaître _enliger_ sauf dans ses usages techniques contribue au flou qui règne. Chacun en a sa compréhension personnelle et il n'est guère possible de la confronter avec une source vraiment fiable, ce qui laisse place à une constellation de significations possibles. Peut-être aussi est-ce ça, le vivant d'une langue?

Comment: ‘**Dictionary**, _n_. A malevolent literacy device for cramping the growth of a language and making it hard and inelastic.’  — Ambrose Bierce, _The Devil’s Dictionary_

Comment: Je vous en prie. Je me demandais quelle était la source pour ces acceptions Qc. _d'enligner qqn./s'enligner_ ; d'ailleurs j'ai retrouvé ce premier sens dans un article [récent](http://www.lapresse.ca/cinema/cinema-quebecois/201704/10/01-5087139-cest-le-coeur-qui-meurt-en-dernier-au-nom-de-la-mere.php). Je viens de voir étrangement que je ne trouve ni aligner ni enligner au [Glossaire](http://www.lapresse.ca/cinema/cinema-quebecois/201704/10/01-5087139-cest-le-coeur-qui-meurt-en-dernier-au-nom-de-la-mere.php) du parler ... (1930). Bonne citation de Bierce, sans doute appuyée par la BDL... : /2

Comment: _Il est inutile de prolonger l’énumération d’exemples de ce type; ils sont très nombreux et prouvent bien que les dictionnaires ne sont pas à l’abri de lacunes._ (BDL), tentant de débusquer certains trucs avec la recherche plein texte [en rapport avec](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3305) d'autres choses, mais quand même. C'est toujours un sujet pas facile que l'usage au Québec. J'aime au moins savoir qu'il y a une différence d'avec l'Europe et je ne le savais pas pour des trucs comme _plusieurs_ (voir BDL) ou _toast_ (voir GDT) avant de venir ici et rechercher...

Comment: @Feelew Je me dis que ce flou-là est tissé de pragmatisme, que le vivant de la langue s'adapte à ce dont il a besoin, à ce qui lui est utile et qui lui permet d'avancer constamment, de manière autonome et culturellement auto-référencée, sans avoir à réinventer la roue à tout bout de champ. J'aime ma langue française du Québec !

Comment: Votre générosité à partager de petites curiosités que vous découvrez, et le nombre de celles-ci, sont admirables et impressionnantes. Grâce à vous, je me réconcilie un peu avec la BDL (limitations des dictionnaires), découvre que la compréhension du terme _plusieurs_ varie de part et d'autre de la _mare aux harengs_ (San Antonio) et que _toast_ est masculin en Europe. Pas mal pour 3 commentaires.