# Quelle serait une tournure plus soignée qui exprimerait la même idée que «Tu t’arranges pour faire la manchette »?

Tags: expressions, choix-de-mot, verbes, lexique

Il est surtout question du verbe «s’arranger », lequel ne semble point convenir selon le contexte. Je cherche un verbe équivalent, un verbe qui s’adapterait bien dans la phrase et qui serait révélateur de ce que je souhaite exprimer.

Il en va de même pour «Tu t’enlignes pour faire partie des prochains lauréats ». Ici le verbe « s’enligner » est employé au sens de «se diriger vers la réalisation d’un but », « être sur la bonne voie pour ». À en juger par sa définition, son emploi constituerait une erreur de lexique, mais il s’agit bien d’une expression que je dis souvent et que je souhaite, dans la mesure du possible, corriger.

Merci.

Comment: Dans quelle région de la francophonie peut-on entendre ces expressions, et, que représente la ‘manchette’ ? — *Tu te prépares …* devrait convenir.

Comment: Faire la manchette: faire la une des journaux, faire la première page.

Comment: Pas facile de répondre à la première partie car tu dis que "s'arranger" ne semble pas convenir et qu'il faudrait un verbe évocateur de ce que tu souhaites exprimer, mais sans nous dire justement ce que tu souhaites exprimer. Quant à s'enligner, essentiellement inconnu de ce côté-ci de l'Atlantique, une question a déjà été posée à son propos : https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/25295/enligner-un-terme-compr%C3%A9hensible

Comment: Pour *une tournure plus soignée* (débarrassée de son influence régionale) : « [Tu te prépares à |Tu es prêt pour] faire la une des journaux » ou  comme le suggère @yagmoth555 « Tu es en bonne voie pour … »

Comment: On emploie habituellement « réaliser un but » et non « accomplir un but » : https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?year_start=1800&year_end=2008&content=accomplir+un+but%2Cr%C3%A9aliser+un+but&corpus=7&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Caccomplir%20un%20but%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cr%C3%A9aliser%20un%20but%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Caccomplir%20un%20but%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cr%C3%A9aliser%20un%20but%3B%2Cc0 
 « Dire dans l'oral » relève du pléonasme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si je devais paraphraser "tu t'arranges pour faire la manchette" , j'aurais plutôt tendance à dire "tu magouilles" (familier) ou encore "tu manoeuvres/navigues" (plus gracieux et moins connoté négativement) ou "tu manigances" (connoté négativement, mais soigné). Le choix plus précis d'un mot dépend surtout du contexte (que j'ai du mal à saisir dans cette question), mais "s'arranger" implique une action de la part du sujet, alors que "être en bonne voie" est plutôt une constatation de la réalisation prochaine d'un but (causée par le sujet OU par des éléments extérieurs).

Answer (score 1):

De manière plus gracieuse je dirais;

***Tu es en bonne voie*** pour faire partie des prochains lauréats.

ou un peu moins gracieux, mais qui veut dire la même chose;

***Partie comme c'est là*** tu va faire la manchette.

Comment: Tu es en bonne voie, voulais-tu écrire? 

Comment: @user25275 Effectivement.. merci de le pointer :)

Comment: parti et non partie ?