# What does "pour ça" mean here?

Tags: sens

<sup>*(This is question #2 (of 3), about the same text that I quote in this question).*</sup>

Question: what does the "pour ça" mean in the text below? I cannot figure it out at all. If I attempt to translate the sentence that the "pour ça" is in, I end up having to completely ignore the "pour ça".

> -J'ai une version d'un côté, j'ai une autre version de l'autre, chacun a sa vérité, c'est correct, mais leurs vérités sont trop à l'opposé.
>
> Donc, moi, ce que ça m'apporterait de les mettre ensemble, c'est de voir: y a-t-il comme une espèce de juste milieu vers quoi on peut s'enligner **pour ça**.
>
> Là, ce que cet enfant-là a besoin, c'est que ses parents réussissent à s'entendre un minimum.
>
> Un minimum.

If I try to articulate my confusion:

- I don't know what the "ça" is referring to
- I don't know how "for that" relates to the rest of the sentence, in "Is there a kind of happy medium that we could move towards **'for that'** ". Does "for that" mean "for the sake of that", perhaps? Or perhaps "in order to accomplish that"?
- What is "for that" attached to: eg, is it attached to "happy medium" ("happy medium for that") or is it attached to "move towards" ("move towards for that")?

Comment: I read it as "malgré ça", i.e. despite the difficulty: Though the two versions of the truth are directly opposed, *for all that*, I still want to see if I can find a happy medium to reconcile them. But I don't know if this is the right reading, hence comment rather than answer.

Comment: If this is a transcript of a person speaking, you need to provide context, including the country. I think s'enligner is probably s'aligner. In speaking, the ça's are tacked on all over the place. Speech is not writing.

Comment: Not that this implies the same meaning in another context, but I just had this song pop into my head: [« Ma maison c'est ta maison »](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6xKKHp_DDOA) from Notre-Dame de Paris (by Québécois lyricist Luc Plamondon). « Tes amis les gargouilles sont aussi mes amis : c'est elles qui me font rire le jour quand je m'ennuie. Et toi tu leur ressembles, tu me plais **pour ça**, même si j'ai peur de toi toujours quand je te vois. »

Comment: y a-t-il comme une espèce de juste milieu vers quoi on peut s'enligner pour ça. After thinking about this: **Is there some way, like a middle ground, where we could could be on the same page for this?** I prefer middle ground to happy medium here. And be on the same page for this s'enligner, s'aligner. "pour ça" is marked as spoken French here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Je suis pas mal d'accord avec ton intuition (essentiellement *afin de/pour les besoins de*) et la lecture faite dans une autre [réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/49924) (en particulier la référence à la *situation dans son ensemble*). On a certainement entendu ça au Québec ; ce *pour ça* n'est pas essentiel à la phrase qui fonctionne parfaitement sans, avec le même sens.

Je pensais initialement que cette espèce de renforcement visait « mettre ensemble » (« ...vers quoi on peut s'enligner pour les mettre ensemble »), mettre ensemble leur vérité opposée, mais je pense finalement que *mettre ensemble* réfère à les réunir physiquement (médiation) et on veut à tout prix éviter de prononcer le mot (faire un) *compromis*. Peu importe, dans un tel contexte je remonte en amont (« ...sont trop à l'opposé ») et je choisis de lire « pour (**régler**) ça », soit ramener au « milieu » leur vérité trop opposée...

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, this sentence puzzles me too but because of the verb *[s'enligner](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/25295/enligner-un-terme-compr%C3%A9hensible)* which is unused in France.

I assume it is close to *s'aligner* and means here *se diriger vers* so I would rephrase it:

> Donc, moi, ce que ça m'apporterait de les mettre ensemble, c'est de voir: y a-t-il comme une espèce de juste milieu vers quoi on peut se diriger pour ça.

where I understand *pour ça* either to refer to the whole issue: these two contradicting truths (*y a-t-il pour répondre à cette question une espèce de juste milieu vers lequel on peut se diriger*) or to be a colloquial redundant way to say *vers ça*: (*y a-t-il comme une espèce de juste milieu vers quoi on peut se diriger vers ça*).

*[Juste milieu](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juste_milieu)* is an idiom. Wikipedia matches it to *[Golden mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_mean_(philosophy))*.

Comment: it was really helpful to me to read your two paraphrases. i've been realizing that prepositions (in English, too!) such as *pour* can imply many different meanings for different sentences, and it's not obvious to a learner what those possible meanings could be! this is even more true, it seems, in colloquial language!